# How to prove this integral operator is bounded

Tags: analysis, functional-analysis, operator-theory

Consider the integral operator $f\to g$:

$$g(s)=\int_0^\infty\frac{f(t)}{t+s}\, dt$$

The above operator is the result of applying the Laplace transform twice.

1) What is the name of this operator?

2) How do we prove that this operator is bounded map of $L^p$ to $L^p$, for $1<p<\infty$?

I tried using Holder's inequality to estimate $g(s)$ but unfortunately it doesn't work out in the end.

Comment: it maybe related to the [Hilbert transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert_transform)?

Comment: @AccidentalFourierTransform It does look similar, however Hilbert integral integration is from negative infinity to infinity.

Comment: Am I correct in assuming that $f$ and $g$ are defined on $(0,\infty)$?

Comment: @Math1000 yes you are right

Comment: By the way, @yoyostein this is known as the "Hardy Transform". I also wrote a question about it. I assume you got it from W. Schlag's book?

Comment: @rubikscube09 Thanks for the name. I forgot where I got it from though, it has been some years ago.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose $\lim_{n\to\infty}s_n=s$. Then for all $n$,
\begin{align}
|g(s_n)-g(s)| &= \left| \int_0^\infty \left(\frac{f(t)}{t+s_n}-\frac{f(t)}{t+s}\right)\ \sf dt\right|\\
&= \left| \int_0^\infty \frac{f(t)(s_n-s)}{(t+s_n)(t+s)}\ \sf dt\right|\\
&= \left| \int_s^\infty \frac{f(t-s)(s_n-s)}{(t+s_n-s)t}\ \sf dt\right|\\
&\leqslant  \int_s^\infty \left(\frac{|f(t-s)|}t\right)\left(\frac{|s_n-s|}{|(t+s_n-s)|}\right)\ \sf dt\\
&\leqslant \int_s^\infty\left(\frac{|f(t-s)|}t\right)\ \sf dt<\infty,
\end{align}
as $$g(s) = \int_s^\infty \left(\frac{f(t-s)}t\right)\ \sf dt<\infty. $$
From dominated convergence we conclude that
\begin{align}\lim_{n\to\infty}|g(s_n)-g(s)|&\leqslant \lim_{n\to\infty}\int_s^\infty \left(\frac{|f(t-s)|}t\right)\left(\frac{|s_n-s|}{|(t+s_n-s)|}\right)\ \sf dt\\
&= \int_s^\infty\lim_{n\to\infty} \left(\frac{|f(t-s)|}t\right)\left(\frac{|s_n-s|}{|(t+s_n-s)|}\right)\ \sf dt\\
&=0.
\end{align}
It follows that $g$ is continuous and therefore bounded.